# All for the same part number, SUM from one table, Avg from another

Tags: sql-server

New to SQL Server but used PL/SQL a bit.
Trying to create a query which will take a part number and sum up the stock on hand, then average the QTY sold in the last 180 days. This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT  
    S.PartNum, S.PartDescription, S.CLASSID, SUM(D.STOCK), AVG(S2.QTY)    
  FROM PARTWHSE AS D    
    JOIN PART AS S ON S.PartNum = D.PartNum  
    LEFT JOIN PARTTRAN AS S2 ON S2.PartNum = S.PartNum  
  WHERE S.TRACKCODE = 0
    AND S2.TRANDATE >= (GETDATE() -180)  
  GROUP BY PartNum, PartDescription, CLASSID;
```

The issue is my sum keeps coming in way off (over), which leads me to believe it is bringing in too many rows when I sum it. Average values are fine. Sum without the average is fine.

Sample Data Table 01
  PartNum | STOCK    |
101.123   |   100    |
101.123   |   250    |
101.123   |   150    |

Sample Data Table 02

PartNum |   QTY
101.123   |      200
101.123   |      200
101.123   |      200

Current Outcome
`S.PartNum` | `Sum(D.STOCK)` | `AVERAGE (S2.QTY)`
101.123   |   3,000      |      200

Desired outcome
`S.PartNum` | `Sum (STOCK)` | `AVERAGE (S2.QTY)`
101.123   |     500      |      200

Any help would be much appreciated. Preferably in a single query.

Comment: To have better help, it will be better if you please post sample data for all three tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 sub-queries with appropriate aggregate functions and grouping. The problem of your data that you have different table for STOCK and QTY and there is no correlation between rows of this tables (by timestamp or some other key).

```
select p.PartNum, isnull(s.Stock, 0) as Stock, isnull(q.Qty, 0) as Qty
from PART p
left join
(
    select s.PartNum, sum(s.Stock) as Stock
    from PARTWHSE s
    group by s.PartNum
) s on s.PartNum = p.PartNum
left join
(
    select q.PartNum, avg(q.QTY) as Qty
    from PARTTRAN q
    group by q.PartNum
) q on q.PartNum = p.PartNum
```

Comment: Thanks Oryol. Spot on this worked well. Sub queries FTW